# Whats wrong with this code ? (Caulculator in JAVA)

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I saw a tutorial on youtube and tried to follow the video , 
I finished to build the calculator buttons , and my problem is that ECLIPSE does not 
tell me what exactly the problem is and in which line...

Can someone pls help me with this code ?

all it says is this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1090)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at Calculator.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:130)
at Calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:146)
```

The code :

```
  package Calculator;

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.Insets;

  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;


   public class Calculator extends JPanel {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 320;

    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;

    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;


    private JButton[] numberButtons;

    private JButton[] opButtons;



    private int[][] numConstraints = new int[][] {

                    {0, 5, 2, 1},
                    {0, 4, 1, 1},
                    {1, 4, 1, 1},
                    {2, 4, 1, 1},
                    {0, 3, 1, 1},
                    {1, 3, 1, 1},
                    {2, 3, 1, 1},
                    {0, 2, 1, 1},
                    {1, 2, 1, 1},
                    {2, 2, 1, 1},

    };



   private int[][] opConstraints = new int[][] {

     {2, 5, 1, 1},
     {3, 4, 1, 2},
       {3, 3, 1, 1},
       {3, 2, 1, 1},
      {3, 1, 1, 1},
       {2, 1, 1, 1},
      {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1},


    };




    public Calculator(){

            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));

            layout = new GridBagLayout();
            layout.columnWidths = new int[] {80, 80, 80, 80};
            layout.rowHeights = new int[] {80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80};
            setLayout(layout);



            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            numberButtons = new JButton[10];



            for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++)

            {

                    numberButtons[i] = new JButton("" + i);

                    gbc.gridx =     numConstraints[i][0];
                    gbc.gridy = numConstraints[i][1];
                    gbc.gridwidth = numConstraints[i][2];
                    gbc.gridheight = numConstraints[i][3];
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                    gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

                    add(numberButtons[i], gbc);
            }


          opButtons = new JButton[8];


          opButtons[0] = new JButton(".");
        opButtons[1] = new JButton("=");
        opButtons[2] = new JButton("+");
          opButtons[3] = new JButton("-");
        opButtons[4] = new JButton("*");
          opButtons[5] = new JButton("/");
          opButtons[6] = new JButton("c");
          opButtons[6] = new JButton("+/-");



       for(int i = 0; i < opButtons.length; i++)

        {


                 gbc.gridx =     opConstraints[i][0];
                gbc.gridy = opConstraints[i][1];
                 gbc.gridwidth = opConstraints[i][2];
               gbc.gridheight = opConstraints[i][3];

              add(opButtons[i],gbc);
        }




    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new Calculator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: at Calculator.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:130)  130 is the code line (?)

Comment: A quick look makes it seem like you have a problem with `frame.add(new Calculator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);`. Without more information however, we can't say what is wrong.

Comment: very low quality question.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opButtons[6] = new JButton("+/-"); should be with index 7 instead.

The loop below would add null valued opButtons [7] causing the Exception.